# Unable to import coroutines in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

When I am using following in one of the .kt files,

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
```

I am getting compilation error saying "Unresolved reference: coroutines".

Context: I am building Android App using Kotlin in Android Studio.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: can you show your gradle file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are importing the library in your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.2'
    // Other dependencies here...
}
```